# “This field is required” when all fields are filled in Django

Tags: django, forms

I have removed some useless branch from my git and now one function on my website does not work. It is about add_recipe does not work. When I am trying to add it and every field is filled, i push the button "add recipe" it shows that ingrediend field is required.

View:

```
def add_recipe(request):

     add_recipe = RecipeForm(request.POST)
     print(add_recipe['ingredients'].value())
     if add_recipe.is_valid():
          add_recipe.save()
          return redirect('success_added_recipe')

     return render(request, 'drinks/add_recipe.html', {'RecipeForm': add_recipe})
```

Form:

```
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['recipe_name', 'preparation', 'ingredients', 'recipe_image']
```

debug.log

```
(0.000) SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"; args=()
(0.001) SELECT "drinks_ingredient"."id", "drinks_ingredient"."ingredient_name" FROM "drinks_ingredient" WHERE "drinks_ingredient"."id" IN (12); args=(12,)
(0.000) SELECT "drinks_ingredient"."id", "drinks_ingredient"."ingredient_name" FROM "drinks_ingredient"; args=()
"POST /accounts/add_recipe/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1637
(0.002)
```

model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
  recipe_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='')


  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

template:

```
<h1>Add recipe</h1>

<form method="post" action="{% url 'add_recipe' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{RecipeForm}}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your form fields has ingredients included

Comment: yes, but i want that the user can choose ingredients. This is not correct?

Comment: I’m confused. What is the trace back error? When you submit the form do you have form.errors?

Comment: no... you can check when go to link, and you fill in everything, choose ingredients than enter add recipe it shows that ingredient is required...

Comment: Can you show us an error? A screen recording would also help?

Comment: Have you tried rendering the form as {{RecipeForm.as_p}}

Answer (score 0):

Just add **blank=True** in your ManyToManyField

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient,blank=True)
  recipe_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='')


  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

Comment: It did not help... Because problem is that the field ingredient is filled and after i push add recipe it still says that this is required. django treats it like it is empty even if it is filled. I am talking about form for users, cause this blank helps in admin panel only.

Comment: @LuiTe,  Can you please place the Ingredient models also in here?  in your edited answer. Need to see the Ingredient models.